# $\sum f_n(x)$ converges absolutely and uniformly in $[a,b]$, but $\sum |f_n(x)|$ doesn't converge uniformly

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm studying uniform convergence, and am looking for some examples of series $\sum f_n(x)$ that converge absolutely and uniformly in $[a,b]$, but $\sum |f_n(x)|$ does not converge uniformly in the same interval. So far I've found things like $\sum (1-x)x^{n}(-1)^n$ in $[0,1]$.

I don't want to start a big list; I'll accept whichever answer gives a couple of insightful examples.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you have a typo in your example, because otherwise $(1-x)$ is playing no role.

Comment: @MartinArgerami The sum needs to converge at $x=1$.

Comment: I totally missed that, good point.